# The age old problem of small harms, what is the solution?

Tags: political-theory, political-system, economy

The age of problem of "small harms" is when one person gets a big benefit from doing something that cause a tiny harm to many people. So, one person may be making millions, but thousands of people may have some tiny harm from it by pollution. Where do you draw the line?

A perfect example is car pollution. Normally, the pollution emitted by a single car is inconsequential, noone notices or cares. A single car does not hurt anyone's help except by one penny. On the other hand the value of the car to the *owner* is huge. It's worth tens of thousands of dollars in travel convenience.

However, if there are enough cars in a confined space, like LA or Mexico City, then it becomes a problem and people's health is harmed. So, for example, you might have two million cars, worth $30 billion dollars, but how much is the harm? 250,000 people with asthma? 1 million people that cough occasionally? 750,000 home owners have to wipe soot off their window sill once every six months? You seem healthy, but your lung would be found to be black if a surgeon were to cut it open?  How do you quantify that?

We know the solution in the United States: a small group of wonks in Washington decide on their own how much pollution is "too much" and then Washington makes "regulations" to cut down on cars or enforce expensive modifications to them to make them cleaner. Obviously this is one possible solution.

My question is, what are the alternatives? Having a small group in Washington essentially act like dictators is practical, but is not consistent with the principles of a free society. How can a truly free society cope with the problem of small harms without giving quasi-dictatorship powers to a small group?

Comment: This question is ridiculously worded. Regardless, it's an opinion question. Lots of valid answers that will depend heavily on personal opinions.

Comment: It's a good question but I am not certain it's well answerable in SE context. I would recommend tightening it down significantly.

Comment: Short-short version, that is what the concept of class action lawsuits are tailor made for (and are applicable to either more-governed-society like USA today, or even less-government libertarian one). A lawsuit on behalf of many many small-scale victims amounts to big damages to the violator, and doesn't require all those small scale victims to be on-board with the lawsuit, eliminating the problem of "not enough people will care to do anything"

Comment: Whilst I agree that the US, along with China, is probably one of the worst offenders on tackling global polution, it's an international issue, and [quota trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissions_trading#Economics_of_international_emissions_trading) doesn't help. With regards to the US, it's relevant to consider the effects of anti-Agenda 21 groups - low-energy lightbulbs were almost illegal in public buildings. However, even adjusting the question in light of that would still make it opinion based - unless you ask if specific alternatives have been covered by legislation.

Comment: In the interest of fairness, it's worth highlighting that climate change legislation is also coming under fire in some European countries, including the UK http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/oct/23/eu-climate-policy-being-taken-hostage-by-ukip-meps-say

Answer (score 3):

> Having a small group in Washington essentially act like dictators is practical, but is not consistent with the principles of a free society.

Are you asking for libertarian alternatives to government regulation?  I know of two:  the class-action lawsuit and Coasean contracts.

#### Class-action lawsuit

A class-action lawsuit allows a group of small harm people to band together so that their harm is sufficient in total to be significant.  They can then sue as a group.  There is often some reparations made on victory, but relief from harm is the main effect.

Class-actions work best against single defendants.  Many defendants seems possible but would be more complicated than most suits are now.

Some might argue that this essentially moves the dictatorship from elected officials to jury and judge.

#### Coasean contracts

Again, this is complicated by having many complainants and many defendants.  The idea is that you make a contract with everyone else involved that governs the small harm and the benefit.  Each side would be expected to make compromises in this case.  If one side is damaged by the changes made, they might insist on compensation in return for signing the contract.  So this can end up with the complainants paying the defendants.  Not the most socially just result perhaps, but theoretically capable of reducing the harm.

While this can restrict your future liberty, it is a purely voluntary contract.  You choose to accept the liberty restrictions in return for the other advantages.

#### Are the results different?

It's not clear that either of these changes the results from what you'd get from your original small group of dictators.  You still get a bunch of rules by which to live.  And they can be much more complicated to set up.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Note that the solution does not have to be a private solution. It is fine if the government implements the solution, so long as they are implementing a just solution. The problem with a government committee is not that is a government committee, but that it is essentially free to do as its pleases and act according to the personal whims of the members, instead of creating a result that is ipso facto just.